# Proof that $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +) \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x], +) \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product, infinite-groups

[In this post on Art Of Problem Solving,](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h351637) it is claimed that the following group isomorphism holds:

$$(\mathbb{Z}[x], +) \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x], +) \times \mathbb{Z}$$

where $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +)$ is the additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Any ideas on how one could show this?

I tried for a while but I can't for the life of me find an injective homomorphism between the two. My best idea would be to go through a multiplicative group first (because constructing an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}^+, \cdot)$ is much easier, the latter being a multiplicative group) but I haven't gotten far with that.

Any hints?

Comment: Easier to show $$(\mathbb Z[x],+)\times\mathbb Z\cong (\mathbb Z[x],+)$$ with $$(f(x),a)\mapsto a+xf(x)$$

Comment: Keep in mind that $\mathbb{Z}[X] \simeq \bigoplus\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$, taking the coproduct over Abelian groups. From here, follow @ThomasAndrews suggestion and show that $\mathbb{Z}[X] \times \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}[X] \oplus \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}[X]$.